# What are these files in DCIM folder?

Tags: images

I was wondering if someone here knew what are these files:

[image]

I've put it in image format because their file names are weird? I just found out that these files are present in my sd card, inside the DCIM images folders and all images are gone except the thumbnails.

**My images are gone** and **another problem is that I cannot delete them**(maybe format but that's my last option i think). They stick in that folder and even moving isn't possible.

Any help or suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I can't help but your SD card is defective. Try running a disk check on it on a PC, you may be able to recover some files. After that, reformat the card to use it again. However, in my experience, when a SD card has a defect you can't really fix it with format, it will break again. I recommend buying a new (and better) SD card

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Actually I can still use the SD card and access other files, but, yeah, those files are suspicious and probably harmful. And like what you've said buying one is the best and last option.

Comment: Back when computers still use floppy disks I saw these kind of files a lot. Floppies are not exactly known for their durability. These files are not really harmful, they are caused by mangled file information on the Allocation Table (which in turn is caused by a bad sector somewhere at the beginning of the disk)

Comment: @ThanhPhú You should write up your comments as an answer. After all, they do answer the question, "What are these files?"

Comment: Thank you @ThanhPhú, It seems that is the best answer for me. Thank you for information and advice!

Answer (score 1):

These are not files but invalid file entries, caused by a corrupted allocation table on the SD card, which in turn is caused by a bad sector. A bad sector on the card is a good sign that card is defective and should be replaced.

You can try recovering some files by running a disk check program on PC.